# How to correctly consider multi index column names for pandas concat?

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, multi-index

I have two DataFrames that are indexed by the columns `id_a`, `id_b` but in different order:

```
foo = pd.DataFrame([{'id_a': 1, 'id_b': 1, 'value': 1}])
foo.set_index(['id_a','id_b'], inplace=True)

baa = pd.DataFrame([{'id_b': 2, 'id_a': 1, 'value': 10}])
baa.set_index(['id_b', 'id_a'], inplace=True)
```

If I concatenate those two DataFrames:

```
qux = pd.concat([foo, baa])
```

I would expect the result to contain the entries

| id_a | id_b | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
|  | 2 | 10 |

However, I get

| id_a | id_b | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 10 |

`id_a` gets a non-existing new value "2"

(At least I would expect to get a warning, that the order of the id columns is different.)

=> How can I concatenate those two indexed DataFrames, correctly considering the index column names?

Following variants did not help:

```
qux = pd.concat([foo, baa], names=['id_a', 'id_b'])
```

Maybe it would work somehow using the options `keys` and/or `levels` but I did not manage to do so.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

Comment: if you reset the index on both - you'll get the expected output

Comment: Try `pd.concat([foo.reset_index(), baa.reset_index()]).set_index(foo.index.names)`

Answer (score 0):

`pd.concat` does not have an option for that (If it does, please let me know).

As a workaround one can manually fix the index of the second DataFrame before concatenation:

a)

```
baa = baa.reorder_levels(foo.index.names)
qux = pd.concat([foo, baa])
```

b)

```
baa_fixed = baa.reset_index().set_index(foo.index.names)
qux = pd.concat([foo, baa_fixed])
```

or reset the index of both DataFrames, concat and set the index again:

c)

```
foo.reset_index(inplace=True)
baa.reset_index(inplace=True)

qux = pd.concat([foo, baa])
qux.set_index(['id_a', 'id_b'], inplace=True)
```